# New light not working even though there is power

Tags: lighting

I am installing a new light in a bedroom that has no existing ceiling lights.  I have pigtail spliced off an existing outlet circuit in the attic using 14/3 romex and run that to the location of the light fixture. After installing the light fixture, putting in a bulb I know to be good (I checked it in another room) and turning the power back on at the breaker, the light does not come on. The outlet continues to function.

I first checked the fixture with a non contact voltage detector, which verified there is power going to the fixture. I then checked both the fixture contacts and the wires with a multimeter and get a reading fluctuating between 119 to 121.

I'm happy to provide more information that would help figure out this problem, because right now I am stumped!

Comment: Based on @JD74's suggestion I tried an incandescent bulb just in case but to no avail. This is the second fixture I've tried here so I'm leaning against it being an explicit fixture issue. If I'm reading voltage from the hot wire, is there anything obvious to check on the circuit?

Comment: You should have ~120v reading from hot to ground and hot to neutral.  Neutral to ground should be ~0v.  Is there a switch on this circuit?  With the fixture removed from the circuit, you should get 0 ohms from the wires or screws attached to the fixture and inside of the socket.

Comment: Pictures? Why 14/3? Is there a switch?

Comment: I'll take some pictures (and do the tests mentioned above) when I get back home. I used 14/3 because that's that was on the run I spliced off of. No switch, after my initial failures I took the switch out to simplify things

Comment: If you have power at the black (Hot) wire and at the center of the bulb socket and known good bulbs will not work, you have lost the connection of you neutral.  Go back and check that the neutral wires are spliced correctly.   Pics of your wiring would help.  Lack of a switch is not understood by me.

Comment: What are the  color of the wires you connected to the new fixture?  14/3 is unusual except for switched outlets.  DMMs are very sensitive and can be confusing for someone not used to working with them. Is there a switch that controls one part of the outlet?  If so, turn it on and see if you get the lamp to turn on.

Comment: Wait, 14/3 is special-purpose.  You shouldn't be tapping that without knowing exactly what it is, that could be an MWBC, post-2011 switch loop or even a 3-way leg.  Also how do you do an inline tap?  Those need to happen inside junction boxes, and the wires inside the box need to be at least 6" long (extensions allowed).

Comment: Photos of splice coming soon (need to get into the attic after kiddo Naptime). I'm getting 120 hot to ground, but 0 hot to neutral, so I'm guessing that's the issue.

Comment: Your neutral is broken/disconnected/or the white wire is not neutral.  Remember neutral must be white(or grey), but white does not need to be neutral.

Comment: Remember to check neutral to ground potential.  That needs to be 0 also.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different kind of bulb like an incandescent. LED bulbs have a base that doesn't always seat the same and the contacts may not be making contact. I've had a couple of sockets that weren't friendly to LED's.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried an incandescent bulb but still no joy 

Comment: @OwenMartin I noticed you said the voltage fluctuates. It should be fairly steady. Makes me think you have a bad connection and when an actual load is applied there is no current flow.